# How can I extract only the Twitter id's from this json data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, twitter

I am trying to store only the Twitter id's from the following json data:

> (
>                   {
>               id = chuckschumer;
>               type = Facebook;
>           },
>                   {
>               id = SenSchumer;
>               type = Twitter;
>           },
>                   {
>               id = SenatorSchumer;
>               type = YouTube;
>           }
>       ),

I am working in objective-C. How would I pull only the id's that have a type = Twitter? Any advice is appreciated.

I then attempted to use NSPredicate but my filtered array continues to return as nil. Here is my code:

> ```
> NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type = 'Twitter')"];
> NSArray *filteredItems = [channels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
> NSLog(@"%@", filteredItems);
> ```

filteredItems continues to return nil, not sure why

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get all values for specific key from each NSDictionary in an NSArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018037/how-can-i-get-all-values-for-specific-key-from-each-nsdictionary-in-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

To start, get just the items that have type=Twitter:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type = 'Twitter')"];
NSArray *filteredItems = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Then you can iterate through the items to pull the id...

(I just saw this as a related answer, haven't tried it though)

```
NSArray *idArray = [filteredItems valueForKey: @"id"];
```

Comment: My filteredItems array returns as nil. Not sure why the filter is not catching anything. The filter is not nil. Any advice?